# When the player shoots it is losing life

Tags: unity-game-engine, photon

I'm making a multiplayer game2d and when my player shoots (the gun has a collider too )it's affecting his life and I don't know why.Probably because when the target "hurt" has RPCtarget.all but I don't know with what to change just to affect the others players in the game , not mine. With what I can replace all?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityStandardAssets.CrossPlatformInput;
using Photon.Pun;
using Photon.Realtime;
using Photon;
using UnityEngine.UI;


public class Character : MonoBehaviourPun,IPunObservable
{

    Rigidbody2D rb;
    float dirX;
    
    [SerializeField]
    float moveSpeed = 5f, jumpForce = 400f, bulletSpeed = 500f;

    [SerializeField] private float health = 100;
    [SerializeField] private Slider slider;
    [SerializeField] private Gradient gradient;
    [SerializeField] private Image fill;
    public Rigidbody2D bulletPrefabs;
    Vector3 localScale;
    public DeathsCount myCounts;
    public Transform barrel;
    public Rigidbody2D bullet;

 

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        localScale = transform.localScale;
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        if (photonView.IsMine)
        {
             myCounts = FindObjectOfType<DeathsCount>();
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
    

    public float Health
    {
        get { return health; }
        set
        {
            health = value;
            slider.value = health;
           // fill.color = gradient.Evaluate(slider.normalizedValue);
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
    {
        if (col.gameObject.CompareTag("Hurt"))
        {
            if (photonView.IsMine)
            {
                photonView.RPC("Damage", RpcTarget.All);
            }
        }
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "PowerUp")
        {
            if (photonView.IsMine)
            {
                var powerup = col.GetComponent<PowerUp>();
                powerup.Pickup(this);
            }
            else
            {

            }

        }
        if (col.gameObject.CompareTag("Bullet"))
        {
            if (photonView.IsMine)
            {
                photonView.RPC("Damage", RpcTarget.All);
                bullet = bulletPrefabs;
            }
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }

    [PunRPC]
    void Damage()
    {
        if (Health > 0)
        {
            Health -= 20;
        }
        if (Health <= 0) // check health status
        {
            Health = 0; // make that Heath don't be < 0

            if (photonView.IsMine)
            {
                myCounts.RpcRespawn(); //Here you should to call counter
                photonView.transform.position = Vector2.zero;
                Health = 100;
            }
        }

    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (photonView.IsMine)
        {
            dirX = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("Horizontal");
            if (dirX != 0)
            {
                barrel.up = Vector3.right * Mathf.Sign(dirX);
            }

            if (CrossPlatformInputManager.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
                Jump();

            if (CrossPlatformInputManager.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
                Fire();
            
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (photonView.IsMine)
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(dirX * moveSpeed, rb.velocity.y);
        }
    }




    void Jump()
    {
        if (photonView.IsMine)
        {
            if (rb.velocity.y == 0)
                rb.AddForce(Vector2.up * jumpForce);
        }
    }

    void Fire()
    {
        
            var firedBullet = PhotonNetwork.Instantiate(bullet.name, barrel.position, barrel.rotation).GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
            firedBullet.AddForce(barrel.up * bulletSpeed);
        
    }

    public void OnPhotonSerializeView(PhotonStream stream, PhotonMessageInfo info)
    {
        if (stream.IsWriting)
        {
            stream.SendNext(Health);
        }
        else if (stream.IsReading)
        {
            Health = (float)stream.ReceiveNext();
        }
    }
    public void SetMaxHealth(int value)
    {
        if (photonView.IsMine)
        {
            slider.maxValue = value;
            // The property handles the rest anyway
            Health = value;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't really need RPC in this case.

I see your character IPunObservable and, I guess, added to PhotonView. So its health will sync automatically.
You also instantiate bullets with PhotonNetwork, which means, they will sync too and have PhotonView.

So every player has all synchronized bullets and other players.

It means, all that you need is to check if bullet is from other player and set damage locally (don't worry, result will sync) like this :

```
. . .
    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
    {
        if (col.gameObject.CompareTag("Hurt"))
        {
            // if hurt object is not mine, take damage
            if (!col.gameObject.GetPhotonView().isMine) 
                Damage();
        }
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "PowerUp")
        {
            if (photonView.IsMine)
            {
                var powerup = col.GetComponent<PowerUp>();
                powerup.Pickup(this);
            }
            else
            {

            }

        }
        if (col.gameObject.CompareTag("Bullet"))
        {
            // if bullet is not mine, take damage
            if (!col.gameObject.GetPhotonView().isMine)
                Damage();
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }

    // no rpc
    void Damage()
    {
        if (!photonView.IsMine) // only player can change his life
            return;

        if (Health > 0)
        {
            Health -= 20;
        }
        if (Health <= 0) // check health status
        {
            myCounts.RpcRespawn(); //Here you should to call counter
            photonView.transform.position = Vector2.zero;
            Health = 100;
        }

    }
```